# Does the POSIX API in OS X need more authority than Cocoa

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, posix

In OS X:

I use the Cocoa API to create a directory on user's Desktop, it works fine.
But, If I use the POSIX function

```
int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

to create a directory on user's Desktop, it always failed and returned `-1`.
But I tested `mkdir()` in the app domain directory, and it worked.
So, do I need more authority when I call a non-Cocoa API in OS X?

To explain why I need to call the POSIX API:

I want to create some special directories with attributes, that I searched to use [setxattr](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setxattr.2.html)() which will add all the attributes I want, but I can't find a Cocoa way to use `setxattr()`, is there a corresponding class, method or function in the Cocoa API?

Comment: It returns `-1`, and sets `errno` `==` `EPERM`. Are you sandboxed?

Comment: after mkdir call perror("error"); and check the error

Comment: @ParagBafna error is 2, ENOENT No such file or directory, it's weird...

Comment: @Petesh No, I'm not in sandbox, just ordinary Xcode project

Comment: @ParagBafna mkdir("/User/loki/Desktop/posix", 0777);parent directory is Desktop, it exists

Comment: *cough* `/Users/loki`, not `/User/loki`

Comment: @Petesh I make a stupid mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a nice essay about using `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource`, but based on the comments, then it looks like the issue is that the requested directory is incorrect.

You can easily swap between Cocoa-style and POSIX APIs when the need arises. There should be no real issue in doing this when you need to. You should always use the `URLsForDirectory` method of the `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` to get user specific directories, as they can be different from what you expect otherwise.

You should use something akin to:

```
NSString *desktopDir = nil;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *urls = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDesktopDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

if ([urls count] > 0) {
    NSURL *desktopURL = [urls objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", desktopURL);
    desktopDir = desktopURL.path;
}
if (desktopDir != nil) {
    NSString *xx = [desktopDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/XXX"];
    mkdir(xx.UTF8String, 0755);
}
```

Comment: God, it calls file url need "file://"

Comment: It uses local URLS to represent files/directories because it can attach security information to them when used in sandboxing